# Does this "averaging" function reproduce the same function in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Take a function $f \in L^1(m)$, define a new function $g = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{m(B_{r,x})} \int_{B_{r,x}}\ f(x)\ dm$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $B_{r,x}$ is the ball centred at $x$ with radius $r$.  Is $g=f$ almost everywhere with respect to $m$?

I ask since this fact seems to be casually used by Rudin in the proof of Thm 7.8 in *Real and Complex Analysis* without reference to something earlier, and I don't know if it is supposed to be some special property of Radon-Nikodym derivatives or just a typical property of measurable functions and I missed it.

EDIT:

The accepted answer is correct, a little more detail about how to go from the defn of a Lebesgue point to this formulation, for x fixed:

$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{m(B_{r,x})} \int_{B_{r,x}}\ f(y)\ dm - f(x)\right) = \left(\frac{1}{m(B_{r,x})} \int_{B_{r,x}}\ f(y)\ dm - \frac{1}{m(B_{r,x})} \int_{B_{r,x}} f(x)\ dm\right) \leq \frac{1}{m(B_{r,x})} \int_{B_{r,x}}\ \lvert f(y)-f(x) \rvert\ dm = 0
$$

where the last zero holds almost everywhere for $f$ in $L^1$ by Rudin Thm 7.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a Lebesgue point.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point
If $f$ is in $L^1$, almost every $x$ is a Lebesgue point

Comment: Ah, he does define a Lebesgue point, I guess the formulation he used didn't make it obvious to me that it implied this, even though it makes sense now that I think about it some more.  I will accept your answer when it allows me.